# Copy a PropertyGroup class variable into another variable

Tags: properties

I need to assign the value of a variable (that is an instance of a class that derives from PropertyGroup) to another variable (that also derives from the same class as that variable).

However, doing:

```
new_variable = old_variable
```

Gives an error. It says `new_variable` is read only.

```
AttributeError: bpy_struct: attribute "new_variable" from "GreasePencil" is read-only
```

Any advice?